# How slowly can one be absorbed in the absorbing phase of the directed percolation universality class?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, percolation, cellular-automata

In absorbing state transitions on a lattice, one often considers "active" and "inactive" sites, with update rules describing how activity spreads or decays. When the lattice sites are all "inactive", one says one has been absorbed into the absorbing state. For example, in the [contact process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_process_(mathematics)) of disease spread, the absorbing state occurs when no one is sick.

There are in fact examples where there can be many absorbing states, which can often occur in what I'll call "kinetically constrained" models, where activity can only change if there are adjacent pairs of active sites. This happens in, say, Jensen's discrete-time pair-contact process, where individual active sites stay active unless they are next to another active site, at which time with some probability they either die or cause an inactive neighbor to become active. All states without adjacent pairs of active sites are valid absorbing states.

I mention these models because they're both in the directed percolation universality class, undergoing phase transitions between an active phase and an absorbing phase. In the active phase on a finite lattice, there's still a chance to be absorbed into the absorbing state from a state that had all lattice sites initially active. For example, in the contact process, one could imagine that even when one is in the phase where disease spreads, there can be rare events where all sick individuals recover at the same time.

A typical "order parameter" describing the system is the density of active sites. What one finds, I believe, in both of the contact process models described above, is that the order parameter in a finite system on average vanishes at times exponential in system size in the active phase and vanishes at times largely independent of system size in the absorbing phase. That is, only rarely in finite systems can one be absorbed in the active phase; one absorbs rapidly in the absorbing phase. The exact time for absorption in the absorbing phase in a finite system of size $L$ I believe scales as $\log(L)$, but the time to reach any fixed small density of active sites at large system sizes should be largely independent of $L$.

I am still largely new to this field of absorbing state transitions. I've noticed that the time to be absorbed into the absorbing state is rather rapid in the models I've seen, such as $\log(L)$ or $O(1)$ depending on one's criterion for being absorbed (no activity or vanishingly small density of activity).

Are there models of absorbing state transitions in or believed to be in the directed percolation universality class where the time to reach the absorbing state(s) in the absorbing phase with high probability are much slower, such as some nontrivial power law in $L$, like absorption times scaling linearly or quadratically in $L$?